# Reset terminal after quitting VIM -- colors all messed up

Tags: terminal, vim, colors

Whenever I quit VIM my terminal colors are all messed up.  Manually running `reset` on the command line doesn't seem to fix it either.

I'm using the Mustang VIM theme.  I think I basically need to tell VIM to reset all colors or something before it quits.

Any ideas?

Comment: What terminal software? What is your `$TERM`?

Comment: It's set to xterm-256color

Comment: A screenshot could help to better explain the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I was having a similar problem with Vim + GNU Screen + Terminal.app. Here was my solution:

Create a script called resetcolor:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -ne "\033[0m"
```

Put this script in your PATH.

Then within ~/.vimrc, add the following:

```
au VimLeave * !resetcolor
```

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506504/c-code-changes-terminal-text-color-how-to-restore-defaults-linux).

Comment: You can just add `au VimLeave * !echo -ne "\033[0m"` to your `vimrc`, without having to create an external script.

Comment: Vim may have drawn over the bottom line if you use a background color, which your prompt will only replace the first part of, replace with `!echo -e "\033[0m"` to fix (prints a newline after clearing bg color)

Answer (score 4):

Since the `reset` command *should* have reset all terminal settings, *including* color, I'm thinking that your terminal software is bad, and is therefore also probably responsible for the color bug in the first place.

(This, of course, assumes that your TERM environment variable is set to an appropriate type for your terminal software.)

Comment: I think a combination of this answer and @Heptite's are about right.  The term software (iterm2) has had some major revisions and the issues have all seemed to go away.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your TERM environmental variable is correct for your terminal emulator software.  People often set it to arbitrary values that seem to work without realizing that it can cause them problems.